# How can I find the tcp address for another computer to transfer over ethernet?

Tags: python, network-programming, zeromq, ethernet, pyzmq

I need to transfer data via pyzmq through two computers connected by an ethernet cable. I have already set up a script that runs on the same computer correctly, but I need to find the tcp address of the other computer in order to communicate. They both run Ubuntu 14.04. One of them should be a server processing requests while the other sends requests. How do I transfer data over tcp through ethernet? I simply need a way to find the address.

EDIT: (Clarification) I am running a behavioural study. I have a program called OpenSesame which runs in python and takes python scripts. I need a participant to be able to sit at a computer and be able to ask another person questions (specifically for help in a task). I need a server (using pyzmq preferably) to be connected by ethernet and communicate with that computer. It wrote a script. It works on the same computer, but not over ethernet. I need to find the address

Comment: does it have a hostname?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but I can use nothing except an ethernet connection for this between two computers. There really can't be a network beyond that. Does that answer it? I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: If you don't already know the address, then you'll have to do something like have the server broadcast an announcement of its presence, which the client can listen for.

Comment: Can I get slightly more specifics on this?

Comment: Are you asking how to do it programmatically or manually? Manually, log onto the other computer and run `/sbin/ifconfig -a`.

Comment: I believe the clarification above should help.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but it didn't really help me to understand your question. Are you asking "How can I, lagraig2, find the IP address of a computer?" or "How can a python program running on one computer discover the IP address of a different computer?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcp is a protocol that uses an internet connection to Transfer data, through an IP address and specific port, you have to ensure that those ip directions are in the same range and uses the same port. For example: one pc 192.168.1.50 and another pc 192.168.1.60 in 502 port. The easiest way is using a Modem and set an statical address for each pc.

In the following link, you can find easily in which ip direction is connected your Computer. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17012/how-to-find-your-ip-address-in-ubuntu/

Comment: I know how the IP system works, I simply need to know how I can use 0MQ to transfer between two computers not connected to another network. I know it is possible, but I need to find an address to send it through for the bind.

Comment: I'd like to recommend you pyserial is very easy to establish a TCP communication, I used it one year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could periodically send datagram message containing peer's ip address (or some other useful information) to broadcast address, to allow other peers to discover it. And after peer's address is dicovered you can estabish connection via ZeroMQ or other kind... connection. :)